# Complex Variables Inequality

Tags: complex-numbers

If $\mathrm{Im}(z) > 0$ then $\mathrm{Im}(1/z) < 0$. 
I know that $z=x+yi$, so then the $\mathrm{Im}(z)$ must equal $y$, which should be greater than zero to exist correct? I'm not really sure if there is a way so show this with the equalities that might make it easier?
And then $1/z$ is equal to the conjugate of $z$, so then it must be $-y$, which is less than zero.

Comment: Not exactly the conjugate, but the conjugate divided by $|z|^2$, $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{\overline{z}}{|z|^2}$. The thing is that that division doesn't change your sign.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189)
I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It is
possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: @GNUSupporter it should be $Im (z)$ as in the original version.

Comment: @orole Thanks for pointing that out.  Sorry for such careless mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z=x+yi$, with $x,y\in\mathbb R$, then $\operatorname{Im}z>0$ means that $y>0$. And$$\frac1z=\frac x{x^2+y^2}-\frac y{x^2+y^2}i.$$Besides,$$y>0\implies-\frac y{x^2+y^2}<0.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the polar form representation of $z$ then $Im(z)= \left| z \right|\sin \theta$ whereas $Im(\frac{1}{z})=\sin (-\theta)\cdot \frac{1}{\left|z\right|}$  The result follows immediately since sinus is an odd function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm typing this answer since none of the existing ones are built up based on OP's observations.

Let $z = x+yi, x,y\in\Bbb{R}$.  OP states that "then $1/z = \bar{z}$, so then it must be $−y$, which is less than zero".  In fact, we need $|z| = 1$ to apply $1/z = \bar{z}$.  Therefore, we need to show that it suffices to show that it is sufficient to prove *only* the case $|z| = 1$.

However, $\mathrm{Im}(z) > 0 \iff \mathrm{Im}(z/|z|) > 0$ is obvious, since we are just multiplying a complex number by a positive number.  Similarly, $\mathrm{Im}(1/z) < 0 \iff \mathrm{Im}(|z|/z) < 0$.  Q.E.D.